# Why extra characters ^@ appended when using mmap?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, posix, mmap

I tried a simple `mmap` related C snippet:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int fd;
  char* mapped_mem;
  int flength = 1024;
  void* start_addr = 0;

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  flength = lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_END);
  write(fd, "\0", 1);

  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  printf("fd=%d, flength=%d\n", fd, flength);
  mapped_mem = mmap(start_addr, flength, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

  printf("%s\n", mapped_mem);
  close(fd);
  munmap(mapped_mem, flength);

  return 0;
}
```

However I found that each time I execute it on a data file, `^@^@` are appended on this file. So what's going on?

Comment: Since `^@` is a typical notation for Control-@ and thus a zero byte, maybe your viewer just displays two zero bytes this way?  You could check using `xxd` to see a hexdump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program first moves 1 byte beyond end of file (with `lseek`) and then writes there a single zero byte (with `write`). In effect two zero bytes are appended to your file, where one is filling the void between end of file and writing position.

`mmap` doesn't change anything in that respect. Damage has already been done.